# Linear Transformation vs. Vector SubSpace

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C^2(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R} $ such that the second derivative, $f^"$, exists and is continuous. For $f$ in $C^2(\mathbb{R})$ Let $$ (Lf)(t)=f^"(t)+3f(t)$$

A) Show that $C^2(\mathbb{R})$  is a vector subspace of $C(\mathbb{R})$.

B) Show that $L$ is a linear transformation form $C^2(\mathbb{R})$  into $C(\mathbb{R})$, the space of all continuous real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is, how are these 2 any different? Is it just that I have to show the zero element in part A?

Comment: Part A does not involve $L$ at all.

Comment: Wow you're right. I don't know why I assumed that.

Comment: @Tunococ how does this space look like in general so that I can prove it is a vector space?

Comment: what do you mean 'look'?

Comment: @oldrinb I don't know how to prove it is a vector subspace. I let f and g be in $C^2(\mathbb{R})$. How do I know what f and g are in $C^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @User69127 if $f,g\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ it is trivial to show e.g. $f+g\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: @oldrinb I can just pick any f and g? That's my question what is f? Any second derivative function?

Comment: no, no... not what I was trying to say... but anyways you merely need to prove closure under addition and multiplication by a scalar. Showing that $0\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$, too, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will expand on oldrinb's answer for part A, since the OP seems to be confused about that.

First of all, note that $f \in C^2(\mathbb R)$ if and only if $f''$ exists and $f'' \in C(\mathbb R)$.

To prove that $C^2(\mathbb R)$ is a subspace of $C(\mathbb R)$, it suffices to show that for any $f, g \in C^2(\mathbb R)$ and $c \in \mathbb R$, $f + cg$ is a member of $C^2(\mathbb R)$.

Since $f, g \in C^2(\mathbb R)$, we know $f'', g'' \in C(\mathbb R)$. Provided that we know that $C(\mathbb R)$ is a vector space, it follows that $f'' + cg'' \in C(\mathbb R)$. But since $f'' + cg'' = (f + cg)''$ (note that this is linearity of differentiation), this implies $(f + cg)'' \in C(\mathbb R)$, and so $f + cg \in C^2(\mathbb R)$.

If you need to show that $C(\mathbb R)$ is a vector space or that differentiation is linear, you might have to go back to the definition of *continuity* and *derivative*. You will see that everything follows from linearity of the limit operation. (I don't think you have to prove it using the epsilon-delta definition, but if you want...)

Part B is quite similar to part A. In fact, using the fact that the space of linear transformations from $C^2(\mathbb R)$ to $C(\mathbb R)$ is a vector space, it suffices to just show that the map $f \mapsto f''$ is linear, and this is just linearity of differentiation. (The identity map is obviously linear.)

Comment: Is $C(\mathbb R)$ the same as $C^1(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: No. $C(\mathbb R)$ is the set of continuous functions. $C^1(\mathbb R)$ is the set of functions that have continuous first derivatives. Since a function can have a derivative only when it is continuous, we know $C^1(\mathbb R) \subseteq C(\mathbb R)$. By induction, $C^{n+1}(\mathbb R) \subseteq C^n(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that some people use $C(\mathbb R)$ and $C^0(\mathbb R)$ to mean the same.

Answer (score 1):

For (A), to prove $C^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a linear subspace of $C(\mathbb{R})$, you merely need to show $0\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ as well as closure under addition (i.e. $\forall f,g\in C^2(\mathbb{R}),f+g\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$) and multiplication by a scalar ($\forall f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})~\forall k\in\mathbb{R},kf\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$). Neither of these should be difficult especially given the properties of the continuity and differentiability.

For (B) you need to show the map is linear i.e. satisfies *additivity* $$\forall f,g\in C^2(\mathbb{R}),L(f+g)=Lf+Lg$$and *homogeneity* $$\forall f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})~\forall k\in\mathbb{R},L(kf)=kLf$$

Comment: Part B is easy. But I don't know why I still don't get what $\forall f,g\in\mathbb{R},f+g\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ looks like

Comment: Is $\forall f,g\in\mathbb{R}$ just real numbers?

Comment: oops, I meant $f,g\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ i.e. both are $C^2$-class functions... anyways for the first you just show that adding any two such functions produces another $C^2$-class function, then that scaling any such function by real $k$ produces another $C^2$-class function

Comment: i noticed you meant to say they were in the $C^2$ class functions. This is the first time I ever dealt with this space and have no idea what a $C^2$ class function looks like? $f^"(x)=3x$?

Comment: it is a [differentiability class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_function#Examples) for functions that permit continuous second derivatives; $f(x)=3x$ is an example of a $C^2$-class function (in fact it is $C^\omega$)

Comment: @User69127 The information given in the problem is enough.